# USArrests data frame to tibble with scaling in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I'm working with the builtin [USArrests](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/datasets/html/USArrests.html) data frame and I'm trying to scale as well as create a new column called state and make all state names lowercase. So far I can only either scale or create a new column with lowercase, but not both. Can someone help?

```
  scale(USArrests)
  arrest <- tibble::rownames_to_column(USArrests, "state")
  arrest$state = tolower(arrest$state)
  head(arrest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `scale(USArrests)` is not saving the results anywhere. Just save it with a new name.

```r
df <- as.data.frame(scale(USArrests))
arrest <- tibble::rownames_to_column(df, "state")
arrest$state = tolower(arrest$state)
head(arrest)
```